# Symfony2: imbricate a formType in another formType refer to the foreign key for addAction() method (multiple form Type)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, controller

In my project on Symfony, I need to include/imbricate a **formType** in another **one**, refer to the **foreign key**. 
Indeed, when I proceed the `addAction()` **method** in my controller, I have to add my datas in the two tables at the same time, and it must match to the foreign key and the relation between my two tables.

This my first class/entity:

```
class Zonestechnique
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=150, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nom;

    //getters and setters
```

This entity is linked with another where the foreign key is, look at my second entity/class:

```
class Conformiteszonestechnique
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="precision", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $precision;
    /**
     * @var \Zonestechnique
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Zonestechnique")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="zonestechnique_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $zonestechnique;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->zonestechnique = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
    //getters and setters
```

As you can see, the `$zonestechnique` is the foreign key. These entities are linked by a ManyToOne relation.

I need to include the ZonestechniqueType form to the ConformiteszonestechniqueType.

look at my code:

```
class ZonestechniqueType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom')
            ->add('localisation')
            ->add('commentaire')
            ->add('batiments')
            ->add('categorieszonestechnique')
        ;
    }
```

This form Builder interface have to be include in the `ConformiteszonestechniqueType`:

```
class ConformiteszonestechniqueType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('precision')
            ->add('dateverification')
            ->add('typesetatsconformite')
            ->add('typesconformitezonestechnique')
            ->add('zonestechnique')
        ;
    }
```

So I need to include the `ZonestechniqueType` formBuilder to the other `ConformiteszonestechniqueType` for my addAction() method in my controller. So when I add datas in **ConformiteszonestechniqueType**, I have datas in **ZonestechniqueType**, in that way my relation between the two entities remains consistent with my database.

This is my `controller`:

```
public function addAction() {

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $zoneconformite = new Conformiteszonestechnique;
        $form = $this->createForm(new ConformiteszonestechniqueType(), $zoneconformite);
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ($request->isMethod('POST') | ($form->isValid()) ) {

                $form->bind($request);
                $zoneconformite = $form->getData();
                $em->persist($zoneconformite);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('myRoute'));
```

How Can I proceed? It is the right way?

I think I have to use the collection field in the formType.

---

UPDATE

I change my `ConformiteszonestechniqueType` to this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('precision')
            ->add('dateverification')
            ->add('typesetatsconformite')
            ->add('typesconformitezonestechnique')
            ->add('zonestechnique', 'collection', array('type' =>new ZonestechniqueType() ) )
        ;
    }
```

I have no error occured, but when I display the form on my browser, I have not the form for `zonestechnique`. In fact, the field for `zonestechnique` have a label named `zonestechnique` but there are no added fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a look there: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

The ZonestechniqueType is stored an an array, just loop through.

```
{% for zonestechnique in form.zonestechniques %}
    {{ form_row(zonestechnique.nom) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem before. the fix that I come up to is by adding a default array with blank value in my entity's property. In your case its your "Conformiteszonestechnique". Try updating the $zonestechnique property with a default initialized value such as:

```
/**
 * @var \Zonestechnique
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Zonestechnique")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="zonestechnique_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $zonestechnique = array(1); // or whatever id or name you want to initialize
```

Its up to you whether you initialize it in your constructor or inline but just make sure the datatype will match what you expect to.

The reason why you have this form field not appearing because form type "collection" is dynamic. Meaning, you can add or remove field(s) from the form on both client and server side. It is not the same with other typical form types which are fixed to one form field item.